# How to consume ASP.Net wsdl web service in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am new in codenameone. i wanna consume ASP.Net WSDL web service in which i have to send one parameter with his value. I have implemented it in android using ksoap library but don't know how to do it in coodenameone.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codename One currently doesn't support SOAP functionality, this is planned for the future but for now you will need to package your own envelope as explained in this [discussion forum post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/codenameone-discussions/QOfW_1o8vDs/discussion).

Comment: Thanks sir, This information will helps me a lot and got much knowledge about Soap Envelop.